# How to sort child object from arraycontroller?

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js, ember-data

I have two objects as follows:

```
AC.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  order: DS.attr('number'),
  subcats: DS.hasMany('AC.SubCategory')
});

AC.SubCategory = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  order: DS.attr('number'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('AC.Category')
});
```

I'm trying to output all the categories in order (by their 'order' properties) via my IndexRoute. So the code looks something like this:

```
AC.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return AC.Category.find();
  }
});

AC.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['order'],
  sortAscending: true
});
```

This sorts the top-level categories fine, but I can't figure out how to submit the sub-categories so I can output those in order.

How would I go about doing this in Ember, or should I just do it server-side and pass the data through the API already sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AC.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['order'],
  sortAscending: true,

  // Use an Ember.ObjectController for each Category
  itemController: 'category'
});

App.CategoryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    this.set('subcategoriesController', App.SubcategoriesController.create({
      category: this
    }));
  }
});

App.SubcategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['order'],
  sortAscending: true,

  content: function() {
    return this.get('category.subcats');
  }.property('category.subcats.[]')
});
```

And then your index template should look like:

```
<ul>
  {{#each category in arrangedContent}}
    <li>
      {{category.name}}
      <ul>
        {{#each subcategory in category.subcategoriesController.arrangedContent}}
          <li>{{subcategory.name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it. Would have been stuck on this for days.